# Calculate running day difference in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like tot calculate the difference in days from the current row, compared to the previous row. What I have now:

```
Here is my column is day difference
     **Day_Diff**
        351
        363
        363
```

But what I actually want:

```
 **Day_Diff**
    351
     12
     12
```

What query would I need to accomplish this?

Comment: Basically, you want day difference from first record of the table?

Comment: `SELECT 351 day_diff UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 12` will satisfy the specification.

Comment: @Arvaan Define 'first'

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work (if what you want is minimum in first row and then difference to the minimum, with `table` being the name of your table and `day_diff` the name of the column you named Day_diff):

See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/613d0/5/0) :

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN t1.day_diff = t2.min_day_diff 
        THEN t1.day_diff
        ELSE t1.day_diff - t2.min_day_diff
    END
FROM mytable t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(day_diff) AS min_day_diff FROM mytable) t2
ON True;
```